# React Native Vision Camera using Expo

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-camera

I have an Expo managed project in which I would like to use the [React Native Vision Camera](https://mrousavy.com/react-native-vision-camera/docs/guides/). The [Expo Camera](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/camera/) does not provide enough functionalities for my app.
After following the [Getting Started](https://mrousavy.com/react-native-vision-camera/docs/guides/), I get the following errors when running the app in my web browser:

[image]
[image]

I have imported the Camera module using
`import { Camera } from 'react-native-vision-camera';` and adapted my `app.json` to include

```
"plugins": [
    [
        "react-native-vision-camera",
        {
            "cameraPermissionText": "$(PRODUCT_NAME) needs access to your Camera."
        }
    ]
]
```

Comment: Are you on IOS? did you run pod install?

Comment: @RoyChristo I am not on IOS. I am running the project in my web browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React Native Vision Camera doesn't have web support for now.

https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-vision-camera/discussions/892